# How to pass data from Rails 6 to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I can pass variables from Rails 6 to Javascript:

```
<% @hello = "Hi!" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ac = '<%= @hello %>';
  alert(ac);
</script>
```

How can I pass variables from Javascript to Rails 6?

Comment: If we are talking about JS running in the client you need to send a request from the client to the server. This is web development 101 stuff and doesn't really have anything to do with Rails. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax to send data from javascript to rails controller.

```
fetch('/routes_for_controller', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          data: data
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          alert("successfully recieved data from controller.")
      })
```

You can fetch the controller method and send the `enter code here`data and you will receive the variable named data in your controller. You can also send data from controller to view (j's) which you can receive using the response.